# How to view all images in a folder in order they are in displayed in a folder?

Tags: image-viewers

I've faced a weird (in my assumption) thing while scrolling through some photos in a folder.
I've ripped photos from a trip from my phone and my spouse's phone.
Let's say photos from my phone are named IMG_20220701_blabla.jpg, and photos from the other phone are named 20220701_bleble.jpg.
So their names are starting differently.

The problem is when I open the first picture in the folder (while sorting by the date they are created), and I want to view picture by picture by clicking arrow or button whatever, the image skips to another one starting with the same prefix.

To make it more clear: I'm viewing pictures and opened firstly the one with IMG_...jpg prefix, and I can view by clicking arrows only those ones which are starting with this prefix - not to the next one displayed in this folder.

What can I do so I could just watch all the pictures in a folder, no matter what their names are? I want to watch them in order they were taken and in order they are displayed in a folder, not by their names...

I've tried opening pictures with nomacs but it didn't change anything.
Hope it's understandable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `geeqie` -> sort by Exif Date

Comment: Maybe the number starting images are lexicographical sorted **before** the IMG pictures? So what happens if you go back?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Ubuntu 22.04. It cycles through all images in the sort order as in the file manager at the moment the viewer was launched.

Comment: @pLumo, thanks, geeqie did the job. But I can't believe there is no default option to repair it

Comment: @vanadium, but did your images were named in like two different ways?

Comment: I replicated the exact names you provided. You may want to edit your post to indicate the Ubuntu version, nautilus version and version of your image viewer. Perhaps this makes a difference.